# How to save in database new order of nodes in tree with ajax | django?

Tags: jquery, django, jstree, django-mptt

I use `django-mptt` application in backend and `jsTree` plugin in frontend to create such tree as in the picture below in my Django project:

[image]

`jsTree` plugin allows you to drag and drop nodes inside tree. `django-mptt` application by default in DB create fields like: `tree_id`, `lft`, `rght` and  `parent_id`. `tree_id` field store information about order of nodes. `parent_id` field store information about ancestor.

When user click the button after drag and drop nodes I want to save the new order of items and there new dependencies (parent_id field) in database. Сan someone say me how to make such thing?

**template:**

```
{% load mptt_tags %}

<div id="documents">
<ul>
    {% recursetree documents %}
        <li data-id='{{ node.tree_id }}'>
            {{ node.title }}
            <ul class="children">
                {{ children }}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
    $(function () {
        $('#documents').jstree({
            'plugins': ["wholerow", "dnd", "search"],
            'core': {
                'themes': {
                    'name': 'proton',
                    'responsive': true
                },
                "check_callback" : true
            },
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hello! Have you found any solution on this?